# Hilbert's Program

Tags: logic, foundations

I'm trying to understand David Hilbert's intention in creating a mathematics foundation.

Hilbert's program intention to confirm that we can find a finite set of axioms with completeness,consistency and decidability property .

I want to understand it better.

What kind of axioms would the finite set consist of, axioms about arithmetic?

What kind of prepositions we would be able to generate from this finite set by using a logical system ?
 Could the prepositions  be about anything ( for example, generating a preposition about the shape of earth from this arithmetic axioms ) ?

Comment: Minimality was never a priority. But finitary proof of consistency was.

Comment: Thanks, i edited.I'm a bit confused, did he think that finding arithmetic axioms we would be able to generate any proposition, like a preposition :" the earth is round" which could be either true or false ?

Comment: He was confining himself to (parts of) mathematics, not other subjects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to understand Hilbert's Programme better, a very good place to start is http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hilbert-program/

[By the way, it was no part of the program to be looking for *finite* sets of axioms; it is only required, inter alia, that  there is a *finitary procedure* for deciding what's an axiom.]